# Ember.js get controller of parent route using Router architecture

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, ember.js, ember-old-router

If I have an application using the [Router architecture](http://emberjs.com/guides/outlets/), how do I get the controller of the parent route?

suppose a route like

```
Router: Ember.Router.extend 
    enableLogging: true
    root: Ember.Route.extend
        main: Ember.Route.extend
            route: '/'
            connectOutlets: (router, event) ->
                 router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('main')
            editor: Ember.Route.extend
                route: '/editor'
                connectOutlets: (router, event) ->
                    router.get('mainController').connectOutlet('editor')
```

So how would my `EditorController` get a hold of my `MainController`?

I've tried `@get('parentController')`, `@get('parent')`, and `@get('controller')` with no success

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can access the router through the `target` property of a controller.

e.g, in your case, from any controller:

```
@get('target.mainController')
```

Or, if you do not use head revision of Ember:

```
@getPath('target.mainController')
```

Comment: Thanks! Looks like it is actually `@getPath('taget.mainController')`, as `@get('target.mainController')` returns undefined. I'll look to see if I'm doing anything wonky, could you also try to confirm? I'd like to make sure this is 100% right before I accept.

Comment: Absolutely, I apologize for puzzling you. Using path expressions with `get` is something which appeared very recently in latest revisions. Unless you are tracking head, you should indeed use `getPath`. Updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

According to my understanding, an application is supposed to have only one router, so why dont we just do:

```
@get('App.router.mainController')
```

I have no idea on what is the right approach! I feel like 'target' is storing the object to which actions or events are dispatched.

Comment: Thanks, I can confirm this also works! @Mike Aski got it first so he keeps the answer, but I'll give an upvote! :)